# Re Exporting complete data from Google Earth to QGIS

Tags: qgis, kml, google-earth

I am trying to export Google Earth searches as a KML file to QGIS. How come all existing locations of a search (e.g. Walmart) in the United States only shows select locations. I'm doing a project on food deserts and want to include all major chains and their locations in the U.S.

Comment: just use opendata from walmart? [kml] https://walmart-open-data-walmarttech.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/walmart-store-status-public-data-walmart-eoc?showData=true&where=((businessunit_name%20NOT%20LIKE%20%27%25Reclamation%25%27)%20AND%20(businessunit_status_code%20%3C%3E%207)%20AND%20(businessunit_type_description%20%3D%20%27Retail%27%20OR%20businessunit_type_description%20%3D%20%27Wholesale%27))%20AND%20%20(businessunit_type_description%20%3D%20%27Retail%27%20OR%20businessunit_type_description%20%3D%20%27Wholesale)%27)%20

Comment: Or from OpenStreetMap: `brand=Walmart`